# Combining typescript co-routines (generators) in a type-safe way

Tags: typescript, generator, coroutine, yield, typing

SUMMARY

I am writing an 'executor' that uses generator functions to define sequences of Actions.

I need suggestions how combined ActionSequences should be properly typed, given the types of the ActionSequences they delegate to using `yield*`. Currently this seems impossible.

Composing ActionSequences from simpler ActionSequences is a pretty fundamental requirement of my approach. Complex ActionSequences are made up from running simpler ones in series just like any normal procedure calling another. Some ActionSequences wrap other sequences, adding some behaviour. Unfortunately I can only get these combined examples to compile while bypassing the compiler with `any` or type assertions, even though they run perfectly.

This issue might arise in other cases of composing generators, but the motivating case of combining ActionSequences helps to define the difficulty and understand the constraints.

FUNDAMENTAL PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

An outer generator has to be typed to accept next() values for all the inner generators it delegates to using `yield*`. This is good. However, the use of a `yield*` call then requires the inner generators to accept all possible next() values of the outer generator. This is bad. You have to lie to the compiler that ActionSequences which only request and consume numbers will also consume e.g. strings arising from the types of their neighbouring sequences. They don't handle these and they'll never have to!

A minimal repro is at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=67&pc=1#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-oOCDDmekrvkaoIzpIMgQE+V7rhA7BPg+1jnlw5APs+cDIKKgqPtIT6lJ+yDftkZFDhaRjIPosChBI3rdHIDQpE0ChGKQLAJLIXQkviRiqSS9hOI0njaUotAemIDHzhpLgwYKUCtlK0oAPSeQgdQgFglyIEguiXOMGJWAREBstcyAwMAUAXMgADkoaOEl76csgLiBFAwSVL4Bk+kxIAQAAHlRLLSsqj60qwACE2UlblkCOC+OCbmOu6wZWlwNkBjxwMqcDAJcjVBC1T5hdUVhPsQ7CVbuY3NfljyFWpT4leVyEEhJX40ZOdFLXlrVTVYlVqMUwQIPerDQOIuKddKa0khx97iMqLB3aEu3Ce9yBfVA53qNJA6yXkQHVl81EVuc9J9L4g3DZcinRSpRJqSwJT9BUVS2uwElwWuTHVFgLgsAABge94oLKQ3pgAJBQDJqOTibZJD820EAA). It seems like some missing syntax or a missing pattern that I need. Can anyone suggest something?

BACKGROUND DETAIL

An ActionSequence is a synchronous generator. It yields Actions (which may be asynchronous) and accepts the Reactions after those actions are performed. This approach allows me to isolate and test business logic as readable procedures separately from everything else.

The Action and ActionSequence definition is as follows. Reaction should always be strictly-typed but I'm often having to fall back to `any` to get real cases to compile.

```
export interface Action<Reaction> { 
    act: () => Reaction | Promise<Reaction>; 
}

type ActionSequence<Ending,Reaction> = Generator<Action<Reaction>, Ending, Reaction>
```

At the core of the approach is a loop like this. It just runs each action yielded from the generator, then gives back the result to the generator where it 'left off'. Every generator is only ever going to actually get back the typed return value from its own Actions.

```
    while (!generated.done) {
      const reaction = await generated.value.act();
      generated = sequence.next(reaction);
    }
```

WORKED EXAMPLE

The countPlan handles the number `Reactions` from its `AddActions`. The last number `Reaction` is also the value returned, so the `Reaction` type and the `Ending` type of the `ActionSequence` are both `number`...

```
function* countPlan(total:number) : ActionSequence<number, number>{
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < total; i++){
        sum = yield new AddAction(sum,1)
    }
    return sum
}
```

The delayPlan yields just a single delay Action. The delay promise resolves with undefined and there is no value returned so both the Reaction and the Ending are void...

```
function* delayPlan(delayMs: number): ActionSequence<void,void>{
    yield new DelayAction(delayMs)
}
```

Now when I want to combine the two ActionSequences countPlan() and delayPlan() there's a systematic issue. There is no suitable Reaction type for an ActionSequence which delegates to two ActionSequences where one accepts `number` and the other one `void`.

To start, the Reaction of our combined ActionSequence must union both `void` and `number`. That's because delayPlan() has a `void` Reaction and countPlan() has a `number` Reaction, so lets add that union as the Reaction definition for the combinedPlan() ..

```
function* combinedPlan<Ending, Reaction>(): ActionSequence<number, number|void> {
  yield* delayPlan(1000);
  const result = yield* countPlan(42);
  return result;
}
```

Unfortunately the `yield*` lines fail with a compile error, since the separate sequences must now themselves accept BOTH number and void. The compiler error against delayPlan in [the linked playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=67&pc=1#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-oOCDDmekrvkaoIzpIMgQE+V7rhA7BPg+1jnlw5APs+cDIKKgqPtIT6lJ+yDftkZFDhaRjIPosChBI3rdHIDQpE0ChGKQLAJLIXQkviRiqSS9hOI0njaUotAemIDHzhpLgwYKUCtlK0oAPSeQgdQgFglyIEguiXOMGJWAREBstcyAwMAUAXMgADkoaOEl76csgLiBFAwSVL4Bk+kxIAQAAHlRLLSsqj60qwACE2UlblkCOC+OCbmOu6wZWlwNkBjxwMqcDAJcjVBC1T5hdUVhPsQ7CVbuY3NfljyFWpT4leVyEEhJX40ZOdFLXlrVTVYlVqMUwQIPerDQOIuKddKa0khx97iMqLB3aEu3Ce9yBfVA53qNJA6yXkQHVl81EVuc9J9L4g3DZcinRSpRJqSwJT9BUVS2uwElwWuTHVFgLgsAABge94oLKQ3pgAJBQDJqOTibZJD820EAA) is...

```
Cannot delegate iteration to value because the 'next' method of its iterator expects type 'void', but the containing generator will always send 'number | void'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void'
```

A version which compiles looks like this. However, note the Reaction type has had to be broadened to `any`. We have effectively thrown away all typechecking, although the information IS there AND well-defined. We know this outer sequence only actually handles either `number|void` but have been unable to say so.

```
function* combinedPlan<Ending, Reaction>(): ActionSequence<number, any> {
  yield* delayPlan(1000);
  const result = yield* countPlan(42);
  return result;
}
```

We can use type assertions against the ActionSequences but this is just another way to bypass the compiler. I'm not sure which is worse...

```
function* combinedPlan<Ending, Reaction>(): ActionSequence<number, number | void> {
  yield* delayPlan(1000) as ActionSequence<void, number | void>;
  const result = yield* countPlan(42) as ActionSequence<number, number | void>;
  return result;
}
```

Is there a strategy to be able to compose ActionSequences with delegating calls to e.g. `yield* countPlan(42)` in a principled way without bypassing the compiler by using `any` or the type assertions.

Comment: I don't understand why you're reinventing asynchronous functions by wrapping a generator function in your handrolled coroutine named `performSequence()`... why not just use `await` instead of `yield` and `yield*`? It's not like you're doing anything with lazy sequences that can't already be done with `async` / `await` syntax in this example.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIyugtgI1QgFMATABQBtgIAKAShgG8BYAKBhmAHdhVkYpYtTBUatAIwAGGfXaccEEAIBOxEAkoCAvF179s6JMjF0ALACY5HGGuQIVWNRq3sAvu3ahIsRCgxYOMamtMjoyMCUAFwwEAgExCqMrDaUxAIauDC6UvLw6CowtGkCqNkwUgDcMGUAPDBhEZTVqADUrcl5nJnlPHwCwKSkAIJQaJi0mQA0MBLWnB42dg5Yme6ebN7Q8EhjAYLCwKLUdEIiALIgMXEJScx5fQZnR6Pjp4dgl9aL7H57mAcRK8ArRnp8rrF4vhEp0lukVrFiNwYOQVHhUCBiLUAG7oVCkAB8tFoznQlGxxEY2gJXRgmOQABVULhiEZkMSqQTbOoyRSGDMwV88t8NltfLs3lwhsCJsBrlDEjN8PLbrDOI8BKj0ZiAHSk8nEBh5ZaOLgwVowfDrNhecDbP6SlRIBj3GyKZR0+K9fQCHAEIhkELzQxKMnEHWUdAAc1oAAMGQALYierK8EAwAAkTEybljIptbCddHoQA

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Calling `await promiseDelay(1000)` causes a procedure to be invoked. By contrast calling `yield new DelayAction(1000)` does not. This has huge ramifications for defining tests, in which test suites can be defined against business logic procedures without causing any actual async invocations. Additionally, having Action boundaries explicit not blended in your code facilitates Redux-style time-travel debugging - snapshots of immutable state can be taken after each operation has completed. I accept that these benefits are not visible in the repro, but that's why it's a repro.

Comment: This is very much work in progress, but separating out actions means tests are able to be defined without mocking much like redux-saga-test-plan, but without the Redux!  In https://github.com/cefn/lauf/blob/main/docs/discussion/examples/index/actions/good/test/dialog.test.ts#L33-L45 the dialogPlan() action plan is tested without monkey-patching by awaiting Actions and mocking the Reactions. Having the performer able to intercede is critical here. The same will be true when the time-travel debugging performer is finished.

Comment: For 'real-world' examples motivating this question - you might delegate a bunch of plans like https://github.com/cefn/lauf/blob/main/apps/nextjs-mornington/src/tutorial/event/plan.ts#L23-L30 or wait on state change events to call a handler like https://github.com/cefn/lauf/blob/main/modules/lauf-runner-primitives/src/store.ts#L41-L68. In each case the fact the outer generator adds Action types which the inner ones don't have currently requires the use of any at https://github.com/cefn/lauf/blob/main/modules/lauf-runner/src/types.ts#L24

Comment: _"Calling `await promiseDelay(1000)` causes a procedure to be invoked. By contrast calling `yield new DelayAction(1000)` does not."_ A distinction without much of a benefit in the use-cases you've layed out. I believe that [mocking async functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) is something already well-supported in test frameworks, and the point about "time-travel debugging" could be achieved by writing a decorator or higher-order function for your low-level actions which perform the "state snapshots", and can also be mocked out.

Comment: Agreed if you don't see any benefit from e.g. redux, redux-saga or redux-saga-test-plan, and prefer using async directly you won't see any benefit from this approach either. However, for those who see the benefit of those approaches, this might have the same benefits but less boilerplate.